# Symfony - Get Entity from within another entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to retrieve a record from another entity (or record from the DB) within a entity.

They there are no relationship between the two entities.

I am using `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` and `@ORM\PrePersist` so when the main entity is created it will also create another entity (save a record to another table)

The above is working fine, there are no issues with this.

What I am having an issue with is I would like to link that entity with another table but I need to retrieve the object based on the value of the first entity.

Usually I would write a function in the entity repository but I am not calling the entity manager within the entity.

Comment: Entity shouldn't be used that way ... Keep them simple (only ORM standard behaviour) and use some kind of service to retrieve and compose what you need there.

Comment: You could try setting up a [doctrine](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) [entity listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html). Doing this *as a service* will give you the possibility to inject other services (e.g. repositories).

Comment: I did start off doing it in the event listener but I was worried about performance as it will be triggered everytime an entity persist. I am using `instanceof` to check. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Actually you should follow DonCallistos advice. This is nothing that should be done *inside* the entity. Using entity listeners or event listeners might be useful with certain edge cases (e.g. bridging 2 distinct entity managers), but don't overdo it.

Comment: I've created an event listener. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Entity in Doctrine is an object representation of a concept, with attributes and methods. It is meant to be lightweight, a POPO (plain old php object). It must not know anything about its persistence. Therefore if you see reference to the `EntityManager` in a model, it probably stinks.

Solutions? You could use an [entity listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) called on entity creation and then use a service dedicated only to properly compose your object(s), maybe something like a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). In this way, your entity stays lightweight, the lifecycle management is satisfied and the entity composing is responsibility only of your service.

Answer (score 0):

Entity manager *is* accessible in an entity repository. You can legally use it to fetch data from other entities and to compose your business logic. This is what entity repositories are made for: [Doctrine Custom Repositories](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories), [Symfony Custom Repository Classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Beta {}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Alpha {}

class AlphaRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getDataFromAnotherEntity($something)
    {
        $query = 'select * from MyBundle\Entity\Alpha alpha where alpha.id = :something';
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($query)
            ->setParameter('something', $something)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But an EntityRepository is not available inside a entity model (and its lifecycle callbacks), as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3.1 you can use the entityManager to set a reference. This is still lightweight as it does not instance a complete Doctrine Record.

Example: I have an entity Status which has some states, and it's referenced in another entity. On create i use this method inside EventSubscriber:

```
public function preAction(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

    if (method_exists($entity, 'setStatus')) {
        if ($entity->getStatus() === null) {
            $entity->setStatus($entityManager->getReference('AppBundle\Entity\Status', Status::STATUS_REGULAR));
        }
    }
}
```